# Retopology Newby - Used Shrinkwrap Modifier - Whats next?

Tags: shrinkwrap

Hellooo Everybody:),

could you help me with my little problem?
I'm pretty much a Blender newby, but for a project I needed to get my Retopology after Sculpting done.
So I've watched a view Youtube Videos and I did my Retopology with the Shrinkwrap Modifier.

But here's the Problem:
I have absolutely no idea what I have to do next. I now have 2 different models. One low Poly for the retopology and one High Poly with over 400k Vertices.
How do I bring them together? Or do I need to bring them together to one model? But if not, which one do I use for UV Mapping? I'm just so unexperienced :3..

All the Videos I've watched only show the process during the retopology. But they dont show what you need to do after you've done all.

And If I only Apply the Shrinkwrap Modifier, I still have two models ..

Please help :3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retopology reduces the geometry of the mesh to a lower-poly state. You've done that, which is already a huge step. This will decrease render times.

As you've surely noticed you've lost some detail during the retopology process, and that is a shame - but luckily there is a way to get around that: Baking a normal map. This will allow you to add the additional, fine detail in the material which will be vastly more efficient to render compared to the high-poly version of the mesh. This does require your low-poly mesh to be UV unwrapped - this tells blender how an image will fit on the model.

As a first step you want to move the models into each other - so that they occupy the same space (overlap, essentially). After that go to the UV/Image Editor and create a new image (Select Image -> New in the top bar). Select an image resolution. Set the background color to black and generate it.

After that you want to make sure that you're in cycles, and under render settings find the "Bake" option. Click the "Selected to Active" checkbox. Set the Bake Type to Normal.

Select your high-poly mesh, after that select your low-poly mesh while holding Shift.

Finally we need to tell blender where to bake the image to. To do this go to the material node editor and add an image texture node. Once it's been added select your image in the drop down menu. Select the node as well, and then hit the bake button. Yes, this is a somewhat confusing workflow.

Once you've hit bake you should see an updated normal map. If you get some weird green spots in your normal map you want to go and increase the "Ray Distance" setting in the render options.

If you want to see the workflow rather than read it I'd recommend [this youtube video right here](https://youtu.be/0r-cGjVKvGw)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have done retopology, apply the shrinkwrap modifier and use the optimised model for your scene. It will be easier to unwrap and add shaders. The more complex model is no longer required. Keep it in it's own collection and hide it from render and viewport as you may want to reference it at a later stage.